# JQuery get this and one more together

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I know we can choose two element like this `$("element1,element2")`.

But how can I get this + another element? Something like `$(this,"element2")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**`.add()`**](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$(this).add('selector')
// or
$(this).add(otherElement)
```

Answer (score 4):

use .add()

```
 $(this).add("element2");
```